# Trying to compile with make results in the error "/bin/sh: /Applications/Development/Xcode: No such file or directory"

Tags: xcode, bash, shell, sh

I want to compile a 3rd party utility from its source per instructions given. I have two versions of *Xcode* installed. I ensured the development tools version is set properly by running `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Development/Xcode\ 10.app/Contents/Developer` and `xcode-select -p` returns the correct path. The version number is added to Xcode's name by me. However, every time I run make I get the error message from shell complaining about something that shouldn't be the case and I can't figure out why it accepts an incorrect path. I ran `xcode-select` several times with the path escaped and enclosed in quotes — no dice. Why is shell bombing make?

The error code is 127. I understand it's about white spaces, but I don't know **how to tell shell escape them persistently**. My guts tell me it has something to do with shell's environmental variables: I inspected COMP_WORDBREAKS and IFS but found nothing useful or I just misinterpreted. The former was just special characters not present in the path, and the latter contains tab, white space and newline characters.

I can't identify the problematic file containing the code because it's not mine. In fact, I get this error trying to compile any source code with make and make install. The *dnsmasq* source URL is [the latest version of dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-2.86.tar.gz). *macOS 10.14*

Comment: You need to show the actual code which produces the error. Also, plesae remove the `sh` tag. Either you are using bash, or old Bourne Shell, but the latter is highliy unlikely if you use macos.

Comment: As per the error message, the error is produced by /bin/sh, and the topic involves shell either way. As for the code, I already wrote I don't know in which file the code in question resides as there's a group of files for building the utility from (I only can guess that the file is Makefile). All I have to draw my assumptions from is *config.log* which contains the same error.

Comment: Look at the tag description: _shell_ by itself means POSIX shell. It *can* go with another tag to narrow down the shell. The _sh_ tag does not refer to /bin/sh in general, but to the old Unix Bourne Shell, which you don't have at the Mac. I don't think this shell is still used considerably, perhaps with the exception of some legacy code running on old Solaris machines.

Comment: You need to trace the execution down to where the error is happening, because this is likely the place where we have to fix it. If you think that it's the Makefile, you need to post the relevant code from the Makefile. If you are the unfortunate maintainer of code written by someone else (who is not available anymore), you have to dive into the sources and see step by step what is happening. Not a nice way to pass the time, but what else can you do?

Comment: If the sources you got are too difficult to maintain, you could seriously consider to throw them away and rewrite everything (including Makefiles and so on) from scratch. I did this more than once. If the errors are too obscure and the sources not documented well, it's sometimes the easier way. But first give it a try: Try to produce a trace of what's going on; maybe you can narrow down the source of the error.  For instance, virtually every `make` program has some option to turn on verbosity, so that the makefile can be debugged. This would be a starting point.

Comment: The dnsmasq Makefile's body https://pastebin.com/rXLQTt8g. The issue goes away once I rename *Xcode 10* to *Xcode10* which is not at all a solution. Even, tinkering with IFS setting it to nothing temporarily seems to have no effect on */bin/sh* that clearly chokes on white spaces.

Comment: This may well be! Still it would be great if you show the relevant command. As I said - a verbose execution would be helpful. Also, post how exactly you invoke `make`, and for the safe side add which `make` version you are using.